# Python - Decorator on built-in class' method?

Tags: python

I know I can apply a decorator on a self-defined function during function definition like so

```
@mydecorator
def foo():
    ...
```

Now I want to apply a home-made decorator on the `__call__` method below.

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
spline_obj = RectBivariateSpline(x, y, z)
interp_val = spline_obj.__call__(query_x, query_y, grid=False)
```

The function is not definied by me. Where should I put my `@mydecorator`?

Comment: Do you really need to decorate anything here? Either create a subclass of `RectBivariateSpline` with a custom `__call__` method and do any pre-call, the parent call, then any post-call stuff or keep it as a standalone function and work with the result of `spline_obj(query_x, query_y, grid=False)` ?

Comment: @JonClements The decorator simply times this function.

Comment: So calling `time_taken = timer_function(spline_obj(...))` is easiest... Unless you always want to time the call for every instance of the class, in which case-  using inheritance is straightforward.

Comment: @JonClements Hmmm, can `timer_function` be directly my decorator? I've written the timer decorator and don't want to create another function/decorator that does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Depends how you've written your decorator...

Comment: @JonClements Oops. I didn't know about `timeit`'s existence when I wrote my own. That said, mine also tells me the function has started, which `timeit` alone doesn't do?

Comment: Not directly - but it sounds like you should look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@decorator
def foo():
    ...
```

Is just a fancy way to defining

```
foo = decorator(foo)
```

So you can create a decorated function from a built-in method, and then pass it appropriate `self`.

Comment: This sounds like I need to  write a wrapper?

Comment: @SibbsGambling well, decorator is just another name for a wrapper, yes.